# Why does OperatorApplied by default reverse the arguments?

Tags: function-construction, syntax, operators, language-design

Perhaps this is just one of those Mathematica curiosities, but I'd like to know why by default

```
OperatorApplied[f][x][y] === f[y,x]
```

versus the more usual way one would expect it to work,

```
OperatorApplied[f,2][x][y] === f[x,y]
```

Comment: Presumably to be consistent with the behavior of the function to be phased out, i.e., [`Curry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html). `OperatorApplied[f][x][y] === Curry[f][x][y]` and `OperatorApplied[f,2][x][y] === Curry[f,2][x][y]`

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `OperatorApplied[f, 2][x][y] === CurryApplied[f, 2][x][y]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It comes down to being consistent with the convention/idiom/pattern of WL functions typically having as a first argument an object to be operated on with typically the second argument doing the operating. *Operator forms*, in contrast, most naturally take as a *first* argument the thing doing the operating which is therefore most commonly the original function's *second* argument - hence the reversal.

Well in some ways this question doesn't have a precise answer since you would need to get into the minds of WRI developers (which I *don't* think is a reason to close--the question's takeaway is useful IMO) but some evidence for assessing "typically" ...

[image]

While common it is not absolute e.g.
`Replace` and `TuringMachine` have operator forms with first argument type (*rules*,*rule*) that correspond to different positions (*second*, *first*) in the original function.

Comment: Well, you beat me to the answer, but this is right.  It's called "OperatorApplied" to suggest it behaves like an "operator form", which mostly take the 2nd argument.  It's dfiferent from CurryApplied which is normally ordered in its 1-arg form.

Comment: Ok, good - thanks for confirming. At a deeper level, `OperatorApplied` seems to be the more "practical wing" of `CurryApplied` which seems to be being reserved for more fundamental work associated with combinators etc. On the other hand, the only difference between the two functions seems to be in their respective operator forms? (b.t.w. the naming with trailing `Applied`'s is v.nice - captures intuitively the moment of resolving).