# What is the best and most efficient way to curry?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, functional-style

Suppose I have a function with a signature like `g[expr, _?(f), {1}, Heads -> False]` and I want to access it as an operator by giving the first argument last. I see there are various ways of doing this:

First as explicit `Curry` form:

```
(*curry approach*)
type1[f_]:=CurryApplied[g,{4,1,2,3}][_?(f),{1},Heads->False];
type2=  f\[Function]CurryApplied[g,{4,1,2,3}][_?(f),{1},Heads->False];
```

Next maybe as a `Function` approach:

```
(*function approach*)
type3[f_]:=g[#,_?(f),{1},Heads->False]&;
type4=  f\[Function]g[#,_?(f),{1},Heads->False]&;
```

Also since only two level of calls are required, as a `SubValue`:

```
(*subvalue approach*)
type5[f_][expr_]:=g[expr,_?(f),{1},Heads->False];
```

Now my question is what is the "proper" and most efficient way to do this kind of call. I try timing the calls as follows:

```
data1=Table[RepeatedTiming[type1[f]@expr],{1000}][[;;,1]];
data2=Table[RepeatedTiming[type2[f]@expr],{1000}][[;;,1]];
data3=Table[RepeatedTiming[type3[f]@expr],{1000}][[;;,1]];
data4=Table[RepeatedTiming[type4[f]@expr],{1000}][[;;,1]];
data5=Table[RepeatedTiming[type5[f]@expr],{1000}][[;;,1]];
```

I try to compare the timing:

```
DistributionChart[{data1,data2},ChartElementFunction->"PointDensity"]
DistributionChart[{data3,data4,data5},ChartElementFunction->"PointDensity"]
```

It appears `SubValue` way of calling is the fastest. The new way of `Curry` is slowest. Can someone explain why there are differences in timing?

Also, I don't know why I get a `Pink Box` when using `"PointDensity"`. Am I using `"PointDensity"` incorrectly? (I am on 12.1)

---

By the way, the `Pink Box` appears to be a bug and is reproducible by the following command:

```
DistributionChart[RandomReal[{1*^-7,1*^-6},{3,100}],ChartElementFunction->"PointDensity"]
```

Comment: +1 Good question. For completeness you might consider adding `OperatorApplied` into the mix since it is apparently [more closely associated with applications](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216721/2249). Also, "proper" is going to be subjective/context-dependent although you seem to be mostly conflating it with efficiency. If that is the main goal then including "proper" might confuse the issue; if the broader "proper" is intended (which I would be interested in) then maybe consider broadening the question to "What is the best way to Curry?"